# How to set App Version on Facebook Analytic SDK using JavaScript?

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-analytics

I'm using Ionic to develop application on mobile. Now I'm using Facebook SDK analytic for web to tracking events on my application. But I cannot find method to set app version as below:

[image]

Does anyone has experience about this?

Comment: I have the same question!

Answer (score 0):

App Version is currently supported only for Native Apps using Android SDK or iOS SDK. By supported I meant, SDK extracts the version automatically from the manifest accordingly.

At this point let me advice to send the version string as custom param, something like this:

```
function logEvent(name) {
  FB.AppEvents.logEvent(name, null, {version: currVersion});
}
```

Comment: Mathiew, in the last release of JS SDK the issue is fixed. You can pass the version as following: FB.AppEvents.setAppVersion('1.2.3');

Answer (score 0):

as @elize said in comment
and  in [FB js sdk](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.AppEvents.LogEvent)

you can set app version:
    `FB.AppEvents.setAppVersion('1.2.3.r4')`